# MYSQL in while array, print first result different from the others

Tags: php

I need the following, this is my function:

```
function i_iframe( $cadena ) {
   $x = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM videos WHERE id_peli = '$cadena' LIMIT 3");
   while ( $i = mysql_fetch_array( $x ) ) {
      $option = adios( $i['idioma'] );
      echo "<li>".$option."</li>";
   }
   @mysql_free_result( $x );
}
```

this code outputs:

```
<li>option name 1</li>
<li>option name 2</li>
<li>option name 3</li>
```

I need the outputs should be like this:

```
<li class="selected">option name 1</li> 
<li>option name 2</li>
<li>option name 3</li>
```

the first result from thee loop should print `<li class="selected">` and rest should be `<li>`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18969038/adding-different-class-to-first-div-in-loop/18969074

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function i_iframe($cadena) {
$x=@mysql_query("SELECT * FROM videos WHERE id_peli = '$cadena' LIMIT 3");
bool $first = true;
while($i=mysql_fetch_array($x)) {
    $option = adios($i['idioma']);
    if($first)
    {
        echo "<li class=\"selected\">".$option."</li>";
        $first = false;
    } else {
        echo "<li>".$option."</li>";
    }
}
@mysql_free_result($x); 
}
```

Shoud do the trick

Answer (score 1):

Call `mysql_fetch_array` once for your first element:

```
function i_iframe($cadena){
$x=@mysql_query("SELECT * FROM videos WHERE id_peli = '$cadena' LIMIT 3");
if($i=mysql_fetch_array($x)){
$option = adios($i['idioma']);
echo '<li class="selected">', $option, '</li>';
while($i=mysql_fetch_array($x)){
$option = adios($i['idioma']);
echo "<li>".$option."</li>";
}
}
@mysql_free_result($x);
}
```

Now format your code:

```
function i_iframe($cadena) {
    $x = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM videos WHERE id_peli = '$cadena' LIMIT 3");

    if($i = mysql_fetch_array($x)) {
        $option = adios($i['idioma']);
        echo '<li class="selected">', $option, '</li>';

        while($i = mysql_fetch_array($x)) {
            $option = adios($i['idioma']);
            echo '<li>', $option, '</li>';
        }
    }

    @mysql_free_result($x);
}
```

Stop ignoring errors and use clearer names:

```
function i_iframe($cadena) {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM videos WHERE id_peli = '$cadena' LIMIT 3");

    if($item = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $option = adios($item['idioma']);
        echo '<li class="selected">', $option, '</li>';

        while($item = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $option = adios($item['idioma']);
            echo '<li>', $option, '</li>';
        }
    }

    mysql_free_result($x);
}
```

Escape your inputs where they’re used, especially if you weren’t already:

```
function i_iframe($cadena) {
    $cadena = mysql_real_escape_string($cadena);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM videos WHERE id_peli = '$cadena' LIMIT 3");

    if($item = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $option = adios($item['idioma']);
        echo '<li class="selected">', $option, '</li>';

        while($item = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $option = adios($item['idioma']);
            echo '<li>', $option, '</li>';
        }
    }

    mysql_free_result($x);
}
```

Now stop using that deprecated extension and enjoy a life of PDO:

```
function i_iframe($cadena) {
    global $db;

    $query = $db->prepare('SELECT idioma FROM videos WHERE id_peli = :cadena LIMIT 3');
    $query->execute([':cadena' => $cadena]);
    $videos = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    $first = array_shift($videos);
    echo '<li class="selected">', htmlspecialchars(adios($first->idioma)), '</li>';

    foreach($videos as $video) {
        echo '<li>', htmlspecialchars(adios($first->idioma)), '</li>';
    }
}
```